# How to display NSPanel in front of Fullscreen-View?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, fullscreen

My application rund modally in fullscreen, and I need something like iOS' UIPopoverController. The first idea was using an NSPanel, but I can't get it to show in front of the fullscreen view.

I need either a UIPopoverController-like class for Cocoa or a way to display a NSPanel in front of a fullscreen view. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, none of them really worked.

The solution was:

```
[yourPanel setLevel:kCGMaximumWindowLevel];
```

However, Wevah and SphereCat1 helped me find the `setLevel:` method. Thanks.

Comment: For what it's worth, these two lines did the trick for me. I'm working with a menu bar app with a pop-over, and was trying to have my custom Settings window display. I was running into issues with it not coming up after the pop-over would lose focus:

`[prefsController.window setLevel:kCGMaximumWindowLevel];
[prefsController.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];`

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
[yourPanel setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1];
```

That should put it above everything on the screen. Happy Coding!
Billy

Answer (score 1):

Something like

`[yourPanel setLevel:[fullscreenWindow level] + 1];`

should work.