# Make NSWindow Front But Not In Focus

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm looking to bring a new NSWindow in front of all other windows, but not have it take focus.

I can make it appear in front with focus with the following:

```
NSApplication *thisApp = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
[thisApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];

[self makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

Any clues on how to make it appear on top but not take focus away from another application?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `makeKeyAndOrderFront:`, try just `orderFront:` ([docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: I'm getting the same results...the "activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES" is just pulling focus automatically away from all other applications.  If I remove that code, then the new window just appears behind other windows, which is weird, because the the docs say that "orderFront:" should behave the way I'm looking for.

Comment: @ilollar maybe try [`- (void)orderFrontRegardless`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Hmmm...tried that too, still no luck.  Theoretically, the calls for orderFront and orderFrontRegardless are for ordering windows inside the specific application display stack, not all of the open windows, right?

Comment: @ilollar Just tried it, and orderFrontRegardless seems to work for me. Are you sure that all window levels are the same (ie none are NSPanels or the like)?

Comment: So did orderFrontRegardless push the new window above all open windows (including those from other applications), or just above the windows of the project itself?  As an example, I've set up a timer to open this new window after five seconds, and when I run my app, I click back over into XCode.  When the timer fires, the new window appears behind XCode, unless I "activateIgnoringOtherApps:" - in that case, focus is pulled from XCode when the window pops up (in front).

Comment: @ilollar yeah, goes in front of current application without activating. Just a simple `[window orderFrontRegardless]` on a timer.

Comment: I'm on OS 10.6.6, but I doubt the behavior has changed recently

Comment: Argh...I figured out why it wasn't working for me...I had a separate call that was overriding the orderFrontRegardless...stupid mistake.  My apologies.

Comment: @cobbal: Wait a minute, are you using LSUIElement=1? Otherwise, I would love to know how, from an application that isn't active, you are managing to show a window in front of the active window of the active application without changing that window's level.

Comment: @NSGod just a default application, nothing special required. Frontmost window is different both from key window and active application.

Comment: Yap, `orderFrontRegardless` worked for me whereas `orderFront` didn't.

Answer (score 6):

Try something like this:

```
[window setLevel:NSScreenSaverWindowLevel + 1];
[window orderFront:nil];
```

This will show the window above other application's windows, but without making it active. A window with a normal window level in application A cannot be shown in front of a window of application B, if application B is the active application. (There is good reason for this, btw).

Please use this method with discretion. In many cases, it will likely violate the human interface guidelines. If misused, it can have a tendency to piss a user off. (For example, in my testing just now, the window appeared placed directly over the location I happened to be looking at in Safari. The fact that it was in the way of what I was doing, yet had the audacity to **not** become key, made it even more irritating. If it were up out of the way in a corner of my screen, it might be a different story).

Comment: Bingo!  That worked.  I agree with your concerns...this can be a very dangerous thing to implement if not done carefully.  I promise to be careful :)

Comment: I figured out my issues with "orderFrontRegardless" and opted to go with that method instead, since it seems to be the more standard way to implement this functionality.  Your method is useful to know as well, however.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

The order front methods and level to the screensaver +1 didn't work for me. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393471/how-to-display-nspanel-in-front-of-fullscreen-view/4433987#4433987) from The-Kenny did, though:

```
[yourPanel setLevel:kCGMaximumWindowLevel];
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using `orderFront`, try `orderFrontRegardless` instead. The former isn't consistent every time it's called. The latter seems to work consistently.